# Page Break is only skipping a line

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I added a page break for a `DataGrid` after every 10 rows. So when it prints I want it to skip to the next page after the 10th row. But this code is only skipping one row in the grid.

```
private int count = 1;
public void dgDetails_Bind(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Header && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Footer)
    {
        if ((count % 10) == 0)
        {
            e.Item.Cells[e.Item.Cells.Count - 1].Text = e.Item.Cells[e.Item.Cells.Count - 1].Text +
                                                            "</td><tr class=\"pagebreakRowInvoice\"><td colspan='" +
                                                            e.Item.Cells.Count + "'><div class=\"pagebreakRowInvoice\"></div>";
            e.Item.CssClass = "pagebreakRowInvoice";
        }
        count++;
    }
}
```

Code for css:

```
.pagebreakInvoice   {
    page-break-after:always;    
}
```

How do I make the grid move onto the next page after every 10 rows?

Comment: `.pagebreakInvoice` in css, but `pagebreakRowInvoice` and `pagebreak` in html. Did you missed or mistyped in question?

Comment: @EekTheCat yes sorry that was mistake. It should say `pagebreakRowInvoice`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the output in print mode?
Because there is not an exact meaning about paging in a single html page.

Comment: what do you mean print mode?

Comment: What you expect to behave is for a printing output. Have you tested output of your datagrid in a printed document? (for example print it to real papers)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any grid libraries? For example, [MvcContrib](https://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid&referringTitle=Documentation) has great support for grids with paging, sorting and other features. And you do not need to worry about right css or html

Comment: no I haven't tried any libraries. All I want to be is make the grid go to the next page every 10 rows. Do I really need a library to do that?

Comment: its only question and suggestion. but your choice is your choice. in library there is all logic and functionallity for your needs and its handled properly. less pain, more happy :)

Answer (score 0):

CSS Page Breaks only apply to printing, either print preview or print the page to paper, and you'll see the page breaks, provided the class names all match (check your sample code above there are mismatch names

Comment: Yes I have tested by printing it. It only skips a line in the grid. It doesn't move it to the next page

Comment: What browser(s) are you using?  you may want to consider adding a non-breaking space into the div, sometimes that alleviates issues.  page break applies to block level elements

Comment: Chrome. How would I add a non-breaking space to the div?

Comment: &nbsp; is the non-breaking space character